# problem with IE8 displaying a page

Tags: html, ajax, xhtml, internet-explorer-8

So upon near completion of my website i tested it (as i do) in Chrome, FF, Opera and IE8. Ive not got around to Safari yet, but im guessing its mostly similar to how Chrome would display it.

A page that was working fine previously (about a week ago) has now, along with 2 other pages, stopped showing altogether in IE8. Cant seem to find any problem in the source. I have Firebug and no errors show up there either.

Ive also uploaded it to w3c.org's [Validator](http://validator.w3.org/) and no major problems are found.. (majority are unescaped `&` in urls)

the doctype is XHTML 1.0 Transitional. Any one know of any reason IE8 sucks so bad and is halting my progress?

I forgot to mention my page loads content via AJAX calls. Could this maybe have something to do with it?

Comment: If AJAX were failing somehow, there'd be traces of it in the browser's javascript debug console. And you'd most likely NOT see any ajax calls showing up in the server's access log.

Comment: Do you have a link we could view? Also, does changing the doctype to html do anything for IE8?

Comment: @Marc B i dont use IE so have no idea where those are.. but yes the AJAX call seems to fail/not load. @patorjk sorry there is no link and changing doctype helps me in no way

Comment: With no source code to study, it's really hard to say.  To get Developer tools in IE 8, press F12.  Check the console for error messages related to your AJAX calls (or anything else).

Comment: you might want to turn on IE script debugger if it's not on yet, as i find that sometimes ie have different ways to interpret javascript errors than firefox :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to use a tool like [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) to record and peruse server interaction. Then at least you can see if the calls are returning expected headers.